# Changin text in a file using RegexReplaceInFilesWithEncoding gives an error - FAKE F#MAKE

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I am trying to change text in a file in FAKE code using a predefined function `RegexReplaceInFilesWithEncoding`. But it is throwing an error .... i.e. `The value is not a function and can not be applied`. below is my code :

Note: version_no is dynamic , but for the time being I am using it as static.

```
#r "./packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"
open Fake

let version_no = "0.65"

Target "ChangeText" (fun _ ->
    !! "D:/test/TestFile.txt"
    |> RegexReplaceInFilesWithEncoding @"admintool: XYZ.XYZ.XYZ_0.[0-9][09]"
                                       @"admintool: XYZ.XYZ.XYZ_"+version_no
                                       System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)

"ChangeText"
RunTargetOrDefault "ChangeText"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In F#, function application has the highest precedence of all operations. That includes the "plus" operator.

This means that code like this:

```
f x+5
```

Will be interpreted like this:

```
(f x) + 5
```

The application of `f` to `x` comes first, because it has the highest precedence, and the `+ 5` part comes after.

To fix this, just add parentheses around the operation:

```
f (x+5)
```

Or, applying this to your case:

```
Target "ChangeText" (fun _ ->
    !! "D:/test/TestFile.txt"
    |> RegexReplaceInFilesWithEncoding @"admintool: XYZ.XYZ.XYZ_0.[0-9][09]"
                                       (@"admintool: XYZ.XYZ.XYZ_"+version_no)
                                       System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
```